# Rails extra params from nowhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, parameters

I have a rails controller that accepts 4 params:

```
 def transaction_params
  params.require(:transaction).permit(:id, :amount, :type, :parent_id)
end
```

I making the following PUT request with Curl in order to create a new record of Transaction:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{ "amount": 5000, "type": "cars" }'
```

However when I'm trying to save this to a database

```
transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)
...
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid single-table inheritance type: cars is not a subclass of Transaction
```

The parameters list that Rails trying to use are the following:

```
Parameters: {"amount"=>5000, "type"=>"cars", "id"=>"10", "transaction"=>{"amount"=>5000, "type"=>"cars"}}
```

I cannot figure out why I have a nested "transaction" key in the hash with parameters that ruins all the stuff.

Could you help me?

Comment: Rails automatically uses `wrap_parameters` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html Btw, I'd also suggest to avoid `Transaction` as a model name, the name can collide with the database transactions

Answer (score 2):

Regarding:

> Invalid single-table inheritance type: cars is not a subclass of Transaction

The problem is: `type` is a reserved word in Rails, used for Single Table Inheritance (docs: [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance)), so you can't use it in an AR Model if you're not dealing with an STI structure.

In that case you have 2 options:

1) Rename the column to something like: transaction_type, kind, ...

2) Disable STI for this model:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = nil
end
```

Comment: well you don't pass id to create method id will be generated automatically @DayvanCowboy

Answer (score 0):

> Invalid single-table inheritance type: cars is not a subclass of Transaction

Rails trying to find `Car` as a subclass of Class `Transaction` as we use :type column in STI

Comment: @DayvanCowboy well you don't pass id to create method id will be generated automatically